# How to find the page of specific post?

Tags: posts, pages

i have a specific post and i have a website (example.com) that have pagination 1, 2, 3, ... what is the page of my mentioned post in this pagination. for example is it example.com/page/5 or 6 or etc. every page has 8 posts in it.

Comment: You should be more specific if you want us to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't really great, as it's well documented in many places, but the answer is:

View the page source, and look in the "open" body tag.

It should show something like:

```
<body class="single single-post postid-29654 ... >
```

This example the page id/post id is 29654

Answer (score 0):

You have some very confusing information in your post. Wordpress has 3 different types of pages to reference and from some of your URL structured references you might be adding a 4th.

First Wordpress page is the "Page" which you can create from within the Wordpress dashboard.

Second is the page in which it displays on (this really depends on your theme).

Third the template file used to display it (you need to know where it displays to help locate which template file is displaying it).

From some of your URL structure it looks like you are looking for a paginated page `example.com/page/15` which really is just the 2nd page i reference but hard to tell what you are asking, but hard to tell without knowing your permalink structure.

So you need to be more clear about what it is you are looking for. Are you looking for where should this post display on my site (some place in your site)? Or some where to edit the post display (template file)?

Comment: i dont mean page type, i mean pagination. for example, is my post in 15th page or another page.

Comment: Same page, just 15th page or set of results for that search. Say you have some search for some term and the results are 1000's. Loading 1000's of results at one time is a bit much so the results are often broken down and displayed in increments or pages of pagination. Could be 10, 15, 20 results per page or what ever. If in your case its 10 results per page and your results are on the 15th page that would mean your result is around the 150th result for that search.

Comment: i dont want the position of the post in search results pages of pagination. you know i have a post i know its url. i have a website that have pagination 1, 2, 3, ...  what is the page of my mentioned post in this pagination. for example is it example.com/page/5 or 6 or etc. every page has 8 posts in it.

Comment: As you add more posts its going to move. So if you create a hard link to its paged page it may not be there for when you try to link back to it later. Please explain why you need it or how you plan to use it. There may be a better approach to this. If you need to know the paged set its within the only way to do this is return the results find your result location and divide by the number of results displayed per page.